# How to evenly distribute data into and compute in an apache ignite cluster

Tags: ignite

The purpose is to demonstrate data balancing and compute collocation. For this purpose, I want to load say 100000 records into the ignite cluster.
(Using IgniteRepository, from ignite-spring), and do affinityRun with an IgniteRunnable that retrieves data by some search condition and process it.

Ignite is consistently passing the compute job to another node(different from where I submit), however, all 100K records are processed onto that single node.
So either my data is not balanced, or affinityRun is not taking effect.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Ignite config

```
    @Bean
    public Ignite igniteInstance() {
        IgniteConfiguration config = new IgniteConfiguration();

        CacheConfiguration cache = new CacheConfiguration("ruleCache");
        cache.setIndexedTypes(String.class, RuleDO.class);
        //config.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);
        cache.setRebalanceBatchSize(24);
        config.setCacheConfiguration(cache);
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(config);
        return ignite;
    }
```

RestController method to trigger processing

```
    @RequestMapping("/processOnNode")
    public String processOnNode(@RequestParam("time") String time) throws Exception {
        IgniteCache<Integer, String> cache = igniteInstance.cache("ruleCache");

        igniteInstance.compute().affinityRun(Collections.singletonList("ruleCache"), 0, new NodeRunnable(time));
        return "done";
    }
```

NodeRunner -> run()

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final RuleIgniteRepository igniteRepository = SpringContext.getBean(RuleIgniteRepository.class);
        igniteRepository.findByTime(time).stream().forEach(ruleDO -> System.out.println(ruleDO.getId() + " : " + ruleDO));
            System.out.println("done on the node");
    }
```

I expect 100k processing to be evenly distributed on my 3 nodes.

Comment: Are you sure that your nodes has formed cluster? Can you share the latest "Topology snapshot" message from all nodes?

Comment: yes they have \n
2019-11-06 15:53:14.872  INFO 28248 --- [           main] o.a.i.i.m.d.GridDiscoveryManager         : Topology snapshot [ver=2, locNode=29994e83, servers=2, clients=0, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=4, offheap=6.1GB, heap=6.8GB]

2019-11-06 15:53:13.559  INFO 28306 --- [vent-worker-#42] o.a.i.i.m.d.GridDiscoveryManager         : Topology snapshot [ver=2, locNode=b90ccd61, servers=2, clients=0, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=4, offheap=6.1GB, heap=6.8GB]

Comment: Do you have persistence? It seems that records should be evenly distributed between 2 nodes otherwise.

Comment: @alamar - yes i am using ignite-spring repository for in memory persistence in ignite. Is there a way i can see node wise data distribution ?

Comment: You can probably do that using Web Console.

Answer (score 0):

You execute the logic for a single partition `0` only

```
igniteInstance.compute().affinityRun(Collections.singletonList("ruleCache"), 0, new NodeRunnable(time));
```

The data gets distributed across 1024 partitions (by default) and a primary copy of partition 0 is stored on one of the nodes. This code needs to be executed for several partitions or different affinity keys if you want to see that every node takes part in the calculation.

Comment: Is there a way where i dont need to specify partition as well as not use affinity key and all my ignite nodes participate for all the data they have?

Comment: You need to broadcast a computation with `compute.broadcast()` method and then traverse through the local data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the help! Specially @dmagda broadcast worked well, however with the repository method it ran on whole lot of data on the cluster defeating purpose of collocation.
I had to chuck out jpa and use cache methods which worked wonders.
this is the IgniteRunnable class :

```
@Override
public void run() {
    final Ignite ignite = SpringContext.getBean(Ignite.class);
    IgniteCache<String, RuleDO> cache = ignite.cache("ruleCache");
    cache.localEntries(CachePeekMode.ALL)
            .forEach(entry -> {
                System.out.println("working on local data, key, value" + entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue();
    }
}
```

And instead of affinityRun i am calling broadcast :

igniteInstance.compute().broadcast(new NodeRunnable(time));